# How do I change the sprite used for an object, while the game's running?

Tags: game-maker

**Engine Used:** Gamemaker Studio

I want to be able to swap between two armors on the player character. They've each got their own unique animation / general sprite stuff. How do I "equip" the second armor while the game is running? Is there even a way?

Do I need to destroy the object, and instead replace it with a different object that just has a different sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change sprite by using:

```
sprite_index = spr_armor2;
```

Example, how it may be (`Step` event):

```
if armor_mode == 0 and sprite_index != spr_armor1
    sprite_index = spr_armor1;
else if armor_mode == 1 and sprite_index != spr_armor2
    sprite_index = spr_armor2;
```